# What does the final modifier do in Dart?

Tags: dart

Dart has a concept of `final`. Most dynamic languages don't have this concept.

What is final and what do I use it for?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`final` variables can contain any value, but once assigned, a final variable can't be reassigned to any other value.

For example:

```
main() {
  final msg = 'hello';
  msg = 'not allowed'; // **ERROR**, program won't compile
}
```

`final` can also be used for instance variables in an object. A final field of a class must be set before the constructor body is run. A final field will *not* have an implicit setter created for it, because you can't set a new value on a final variable.

```
class Point {
  final num x, y;
  Point(this.x, this.y);
}

main() {
  var p = new Point(1, 1);
  print(p.x); // 1
  p.x = 2; // WARNING, no such method
}
```

It's important to realize that `final` affects the variable, but not the object pointed to by the variable. That is, `final` doesn't make the variable's *object* immutable.

For example:

```
class Address {
  String city;
  String state;
  Address(this.city, this.state);
}

main() {
  final address = new Address("anytown", "hi");
  address.city = 'waikiki';
  print(address.city); // waikiki
}
```

In the above example, the `address` variable is marked as final, so it will always point to the object instantiated by the `new Address("anytown", "hi")` constructor. However, the object itself has state that is mutable, so it's perfectly valid to change the city. The only thing prevented by `final` is reassigning the `address` variable.

Comment: "A final field of a class must be set before the constructor body is run." - This was the part that had been throwing me the most. Even though I was setting the final variable in the constructor it didn't even occur to me that was the reason I was getting the error.

Comment: @KevinSheehan I was thrown off by setting the final field before the constructor as well. For those seeking to do this at the constructor level, if state was a final variable, it could be set like so:  Address(this.city) : state = "Hawaii";